# concatenate multiple csv files using dos and keeping header from first file

Tags: csv, cmd

I am trying to use the below code to look through the current directory for all .csv files and concatenate them into one.

```
@echo off
ECHO Set working directory
cd /d %~dp0
ECHO Deleting existing combined file
echo '' > combined.csv
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set cnt=1
for %%i in (*.csv) do (
  if cnt==1 (
    for /f "delims=/" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  ) else (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  )
  set /a cnt+=1
)
```

currently it concatenates the files into one but seems to miss out the header row and replaces it with "".

Any ideas?

Comment: might it be, that the first file to process is "combined.csv"?

Comment: Thank you, it was. How would i put a condition to check if that file is there and delete it before it runs the concatenate bit?

Comment: Does it have to be a CMD script? This would be **very** easy in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a file "combined.csv". This is matched with `*.csv`

A possible workaround:

name it `combined.txt`, so `for %%i in (*.csv)` doesn't catch it. When you are finished, rename it to `combined.csv`.

By the way: `echo '' >file.txt` will not create an empty file. It will contain `''`.
`echo.>file.txt` will create a file with an empty line. To create a real empty file, shortest code is `break>file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

The significant portion is (and you don't need to invoke `delayedexpansion`)

```
set cnt=1
for %%i in (*.csv) do (
  if DEFINED cnt (
    for /f "delims=/" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
    SET "cnt="
  ) else (
    for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%j in ('type "%%i"') do echo %%j >> combined.csv
  )
)
```

`cnt` is being abused as a counter. The `if cnt==1 (` will **never** be true - `cnt` will never be equal to `1`. The *contents* of `cnt` may be `1`, but under those circumstances you'd need `if !cnt!==1 (` - the `!cnt!` retrieves the current content of `cnt` - but only if `delayedexpansion` is invoked.

When a value is being used as a **flag**, I recommend using the strategy of setting the variable to *nothing* or *anyvalueyoulike* then using `if defined varname` to access "is this value currently defined?" and then switch the value to *something* or *nothing* to change behaviour. This approach works within a loop regardless of whether `delayedexpansion` has been invoked or not.